# How do I emulate a page break with CSS and HTML?

Tags: css

I'm trying to generate a CSS class that will help me define a "page break".

I know that if I use `@media:print .MyDiv{ width:100%; height:100%; }`, I can then set the class of a `div` to `MyDiv` and it will be -- as best as possible -- 1 page of print.

This is great, but I have encountered a new item that I don't know how to handle, and I'm hoping that something similar can be done. I need to create an empty `div` that will stretch itself out to the "end of the page".

Something like:

```
<style type="text/css">
@media print .PageBreak { 
    width: 100%; 
    height: *; /* space left on current page */ 
}
@media screen .PageBreak {
    border-bottom: 1px solid black;
}
</style>

<!-- ... -->

<div>This should appear on the first page.</div>

<div class="PageBreak"><!--
    This DIV should stretch itself out so that the next piece
    of content appears on the next page (only when printing).
--></div>

<div>This should appear on the second page.</div>
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This is for print, right?

Can't you just use this?

```
<p style="page-break-before: always"></p>
```

There are some other options to [page-break-before](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_print_pagebb.asp) that are worth knowing about too.

Comment: Holy crap.... I've never heard of -- or used -- that. Yet it's so simple. How have I ever missed that.

Thank you. Duh.

Comment: It's a handy one.  I found out about it a while back when I was writing a lot of documentation for a wiki that also needed to have printed copies.

Comment: I use this with Prince XML but whats the support like with different browsers?

Comment: I believe it's supported by most semi modern browsers.  Mozilla/Firefox 1+, IE 5+, Opera 6+, Safari 1+

Comment: Just an FYI for future viewers, I don't think you can use `page-break-before` with semantic elements.  I tried using `<section>` with no results.  When I changed to `<div>` this method worked great!

Comment: @MarkBiek Link is broken.

Answer (score 3):

In case anyone is interested in the solution I used:

```
<style type="text/css">
@media print {
    .PageBreak {
        page-break-before: always;
    }
}
@media screen { 
    .PageBreak { 
        border-bottom: 1px dashed black; 
        width: 100%;
        margin-bottom: 12px; 
    }
}
</style>
```

So simple. Thanks [Mark](https://stackoverflow.com/users/305/mark-biek) and [Mark](https://stackoverflow.com/users/50866/mark-davidson).

Answer (score 1):

Sorry if I am missing something but is there a reason you can't use the default page breaking in css.

[Specifying page breaks for printing using CSS](http://www.javascriptkit.com/dhtmltutors/pagebreak.shtml)

Answer (score 0):

If your html goes as attachement and if the user is previewing the file using gmail, gmail removes any css rule that has a page-break-after property rule.